# Delete a row of a table that has a key linked to another table as foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have just started tinkering with mysql. I have three tables.

```
    PURCHASEORDERS
    PURCHASEORDERLINE(HAS A FOREIGN KEY OF PURCHASEORDERID AND STOREROOM ID)
    STOREROOM
```

I was trying to delete a row from purchaseorders and realised it will be an issue since it links to the foreign key of purchaseorderline. 
Now from my understanding I would have to say (in pseudo code)

```
    delete from purchaseorders where purchaseid not exists in 
    purchaseorderline.purchaseid
```

Any suggestion to how I may express it in mysql terms ?

Comment: `PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + this.table + " WHERE " + this.ID + " = ? NOT IN ( SELECT PURCHASEORDERLINE."+this.ID+ " FROM "+ " PURCHASEORDERLINE WHERE "+this.ID+" IS NOT NULL)");` and I get an error saying `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'BOOLEAN' and 'INTEGER' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation` I dont see where I am comparing a bool to an int

Comment: Get the query sorted in mysql directly before you worry about putting in Java. Once it works in a pure SQL environment you can sort the Java part. Don't confuse the issue

Comment: I am only using java netbeans. I am using Mysql only for the java project.

Comment: So? Get the query right in mysql, and then transfer it into Java. Then you'll know if the SQL itself works. After that you can try running it via Java

Comment: I tried it on pure sql and got the same error. 
I think logically it's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsut use not in

```
  delete from purchaseorders where purchaseid not in 
  ( select   purchaseorderline.purchaseid from purchaseorderline where 
        purchaseid  is not null
  )
```

Comment: `PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + this.table + " WHERE " + this.ID + " = ? NOT IN ( SELECT PURCHASEORDERLINE."+this.ID+ " FROM "+ " PURCHASEORDERLINE WHERE "+this.ID+" IS NOT NULL)");` and I get an error saying `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'BOOLEAN' and 'INTEGER' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a `not exists` subquery:

```
delete from purchaseorders po
    where not exists (select 1
                      from purchaseorderline pol
                      where po.purchaseid = ol.purchaseid
                     );
```

An equivalent formulation is a `left join`:

```
delete po
    from purchaseorders po left join
         purchaseorderline pol
         on po.purchaseid = ol.purchaseid
    where pol.purchaseid is null;
```

I strongly discourage you from using `NOT IN` with a subquery.  It does not behave as expected if *any* values in the subquery return `NULL`.  Because there are other ways to express the intended logic, my recommendation is to get used to using those other ways to avoid future mistakes.